# How to expand balance_transaction to get transaction fee from Stripe Webhook response

Tags: response, payment, webhooks, expand, fee

With stripe i am able to expand the balance_transaction object to get the transaction fees for direct payments, i.e. credit card.

This is done by:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "customer" => $customer->id,
    ...
    "expand" => array("balance_transaction")
    )
);
```

When i use payments with pending transactions, i.e. bank transfer, the fee could not be calculated on charging the payment.

In this case i had to configure a webhook with charge.succeeded and check the source_id that has to match with the initial payment request.

I wonder how to get the fees out of the webhook response. blance_transaction is not expanded. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it is not possible. This would be a webhook preference.
According to their Docs page on [expand parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects):

> This parameter [n. expand] is available on all API requests, and applies to the response of that request only.